# Long values in objects not serialized and deserialized properly when using proto3 in Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto, proto3

I am trying to serialize and deserialize an object in java using proto3. Here is what my object in proto looks like

```
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.project.dataModel";
option java_outer_classname = "FlowProto";


// The request message containing the user's name.
message Flow {
    string subscriberIMSEI = 1;
    string destinationIP = 2;
    uint64 txBytes = 3;
    uint64 rxBytes = 4;
    uint64 txPkts = 5;
    uint64 rxPkts = 6;
    uint64 startTimeInMillis = 7;
    uint64 endTimeInMillis = 8;
    string asnNumber = 9;
    string asnName = 10;
    string asnCountryCode = 11;

}
```

Here is how my serialization and deserialzation in java looks like

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Flow flow =
                Flow.newBuilder().setAsnName("abc")
                        .setEndTimeInMillis(123456789L)
                        .setStartTimeInMillis(123456789L)
                .setDestinationIP("1.1.1.1")
                .setTxBytes(1L)
                .setRxBytes(1L)
                .setTxPkts(1L)
                .setRxPkts(1L)
                .setAsnName("blah")
                .setAsnCountryCode("blah")
                .build();

        byte[] flowByteArray = flow.toByteArray();

        String flowString = flow.toByteString().toStringUtf8();

        System.out.println("Parsed from ByteArray:" + Flow.parseFrom(flowByteArray).getEndTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("Parsed from ByteString:" + Flow.parseFrom(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(flowString))
                .getEndTimeInMillis());
    }
}
```

My output is as follows

```
Parsed from ByteArray:123456789
Parsed from ByteString:-4791902657223630865
```

Where am I going wrong when I am trying to go the ByteString and the utf-8 route for serialization and deserialization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing an issue is because your serialized byte array is being corrupted. This happens because UTF-8 is a variable length encoding and converting to a UTF-8 string changes the bytes in your original array. When you are doing `flow.toByteString().toStringUtf8()` one byte in the original bytestring may be transformed into three new bytes with different values. Then when you do `ByteString.copyFromUtf8(flowString)` the byte changes are not undone since that line of code effectively just retrieves the transformed UTF-8 bytes, not the original bytes you put in.

Here is a small test that illustrates the issue you are seeing

```
@Test
public void byteConsistency() {
  byte[] vals = new byte[] {0, 110, -1};
  ByteString original = ByteString.copyFrom(vals);
  ByteString newString = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(original.toStringUtf8());

  for (int index = 0; index < newString.size(); index++) {
    System.out.println(newString.byteAt(index));
  }
}
```

You would expect this code to output

```
0
110
-1
```

But it actually outputs

```
0
110
-17
-65
-67
```

That's because UTF-8 likely dictates that a -1 (0xFF) byte should be encoded as three bytes [-17, -65, -67].

In summary, when dealing with protobuf don't convert serialized objects into UTF-8 strings. Only use the raw bytes for serialization and deserialization. If you try converting to UTF-8 strings the serialized bytes will become corrupted and you will not be able to deserialize them.

Comment: Yeah we are using Pentaho, which doesnt have support for passing around byte[]. I ended up using Base64 encoding to convert byte[] to string.